# Django Local Installation syncdb ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, installation, osx-snow-leopard, local

I have been struggling to get a local django installation set up on a mac osx10.6.8. Running syncdb fails to recognize the apps that I have installed.

```
admins-macbook:myproject Admin$ python manage.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 443, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 382, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 261, in fetch_command
    klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 69, in load_command_class
    module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/south/management/commands/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import django.template.loaders.app_directories
  File "/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/app_directories.py", line 23, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('ImportError %s: %s' % (app, e.args[0]))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: ImportError haystack: cannot import name openProc
```

I have installed all the apps in the `requirements.txt` and they exist in the

```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

directory. It is on my pythonpath:

```
admins-macbook:myproject Admin$ echo $PATH
/Users/Admin/myapp/lib/python2.7/site-packages:(... etc.)
```

How can I properly run `syncdb`? Thanks for your ideas!

Comment: did you installed haystack correctly??

Comment: Yes I ran `pip install`. It is installed in the site-packages directory and available in my urlconf. If I comment out haystack in my settings, then the next application raises the same error. And so on and so forth. Do you have any ideas that might help? Thanks!

Comment: you might need to work on `virtualenv`. and try to install the packages in requirements one by one using `pip install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may installed `pip install haystack` which is wrong.

you need to install `dyango haystack` by `pip install django-haystack`

please refer this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312374/haystack-in-installed-apps-results-in-error-cannot-import-name-openproc)